# How to find a class in java 12's html javadoc, now that class index is removed?

Tags: javadoc, java-12

I just upgraded JAVA + Javadoc to version 12.
Now, Javadoc has totally been 'restructured' into modules.
Example: searching for the description of 'JComboBox',
I couldn't find it: there's no more class index added.
Finally I searched on disk for a file 'JComboBox.html', but that feels clumsy.

Is there another way to find a class description in the new Javadoc?

Comment: This is not new, Java SE and the JDK were restructured into modules in JDK 9. Once you get used to the search box (top right) you won't look back.

Comment: I won't. Case closed.

Comment: The search box is the way to go now, but if you really want to list all the classes and scroll through them it is still possible. For example, from the home page for [Oracle's Javadoc for JDK 12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/index.html): [1] Click **INDEX** on the top menu bar. [2] Click the [All classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/allclasses-index.html) link on the left of the page. There are also useful links allowing you to filter that list: _"Interface Summary"_, _"Enum Summary"_, _"Exception Summary"_, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the search box in the top right;

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helps. Btw.: I did not know that such long question titles were allowed. (LOL) ;JOOP!